# Kentico 9 different home page for a specific role

Tags: kentico

When a user in role 'X' hits the site, i want them going to /YourSection rather than the home page. At the root node, i've denied access to everything for this role, and in the section i want to see and given that role read permissions. This didn't work.

How can i redirect based on their role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use the Random redirection webpart and enter only a single URL in the URLs box.  Then set the visibility based on the role.  So when the Current User is in role "X" it is visible/active, else it's not.

If that webpart won't work then I'd create one on your own to do this same functionality.

Comment: I never thought i'd have a use for the random redirect. cheers!

Comment: While this works, it seems Global Admins get redirect too.

Comment: Then add some logic for a global admin to that visibility property.